# Read and write from temp file in Roku

Tags: roku, brightscript

In Roku, how do I read and write data from a temporary file in the folder `tmp:`? I cannot find any documentation relating to this. The data which I am storing is too big to be stored in the registry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is two simple functions do read and write data from `tmp:/` folder:

- *ReadAsciiFile(filepath as String) as String*

  `text=ReadAsciiFile("tmp:/config.txt")`
- *WriteAsciiFile(filepath as String, text as String) as Boolean*

  `WriteAsciiFile("tmp:/config.txt", "the text to write")`

Further documentation in source.

**Source:** http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/BrightScript+Language+Reference#BrightScriptLanguageReference-78ReadAsciiFilefilepathasStringasString

Comment: I know that this is the solution (according to Roku), but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: I take that back, the problem was that I was trying to access this from an SceneGraph object, and this can be accessed only from the main.brs file (apparently).

Comment: Where should I place my file if I want to retain the file across the sessions?

Comment: @MayurK In that case I would suggest to store it in the Registry. You just need to "stringify" your file and save it. Be aware that Registry data size is limited to 16kb for each channel.

Comment: Hi @Roberto14! Yes.. I did not use "stringify" but just stored my string. I forgot to reply here. Anyways Thanks for your answer :).

Comment: I write my file in a task node using `m.LocalFile = CreateObject("roByteArray") m.LocalFile.FromAsciiString(m.Content) m.LocalFile.WriteFile("tmp:/interlink")`. I tried to this same file read  main scene using `m.Content = ReadAsciiFile("tmp:/interlink")` It's give error `m.LocalM3U8File.FromAsciiString(m.M3U8Content)`. I don't know how?. any suggesion for this