# Roku: Reading a text file present in server

Tags: roku, brightscript

I want to read a text file present in a server from my Roku program. I reffered the following question.
[Read and write from temp file in Roku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31723083/read-and-write-from-temp-file-in-roku)

The above link has solution to read file from tmp/. So, I tried something like this:

```
text=ReadAsciiFile("<server_file_path>/file.txt")
```

But it is not able to open the file. Is there any other way to read a text file present in server?

Answer (score 3):

ReadAsciiFile() is only used to read files from pkg:/ and tmp:/ directories. 
You should use rourltransfer for this.

Comment: I followed this example: https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Downloading+Server+Content But the creation of roSGNode object is failing.

Comment: roSGNode creation issue is resolved. I was creating roSGNode before roSGScreen, which is not allowed. But I am not getting call to sub getContent().

Comment: Hi @Roman Parashchyn! Do you have any sample code for "rourltransfer "?

Answer (score 0):

The code given in SDK document is too complicated for just to read a text file from server.

The following code worked from me.

```
Sub readTextFromServer(serverURL as String) as String
        readInternet = createObject("roUrlTransfer")
        print "Getting URL from: ";serverURL
        readInternet.setUrl(serverURL)
        myText= readInternet.GetToString()
        print "Text from server: ";myText

        return myText
End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you declaring serverURL?